# Find out all the points on a line using midpoint formula

Tags: c#, algorithm, latitude-longitude, points

I have a route(line) drawn on a map. For this route, I have 2 points, start point and end point say (x1,y1) and (x2, y2).

I need to find out all the points which are on the line. I am using midpoint formula for this.
Below is the code for same.

```
private void GetAllPoints(GraphLocation start, GraphLocation end)
{
    GraphLocation midPoint = GetMidPoint(start, end);
    allPoints.Add(midPoint);
    while (start.Latitude != midPoint.Latitude && start.Longitude != midPoint.Longitude)
    {
        GraphLocation point = GetMidPoint(start, midPoint);
        midPoint = point;
        allPoints.Add(point);
    }          
}

private GraphLocation GetMidPoint(GraphLocation start, GraphLocation end)
{
    GraphLocation midPoint = new GraphLocation();

    double dLon = DegreesToRadians(end.Longitude - start.Longitude);
    double Bx = Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(end.Latitude)) * Math.Cos(dLon);
    double By = Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(end.Latitude)) * Math.Sin(dLon);

    midPoint.Latitude = RadiansToDegrees(Math.Atan2(
                         Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(start.Latitude)) + Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(end.Latitude)),
                         Math.Sqrt(
                             (Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(start.Latitude)) + Bx) *
                             (Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(start.Latitude)) + Bx) + By * By)));

   midPoint.Longitude = start.Longitude + RadiansToDegrees(Math.Atan2(By, Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(start.Latitude)) + Bx));
   allPoints.Add(midPoint);

   return midPoint;
}
```

This code skips some parts of the route.

Please help me out in getting the desired results.

Comment: Are having problem with the equations to find out all the points on one line or with the code?

Comment: A line has an infinite number of points...what exactly *are* the desired results?

Comment: I trying an approach as, break line using midpoint formula recursively, unless all the points are covered. I am not able to figure out the stopping condition.

Comment: There is no stopping condition.  A line has an infinite number of points.  Again, what are you trying to do?  Why do you need to generate these points?  What is is this a map of?  What is this a route of?  What is your objective?  How do you decide that you are "missing" points, or that some have been "skipped"?

Comment: Are you attempting to generate an evenly spaced array of points along the line segment defined by those two endpoints?

Comment: @ Is your point space discrete or continous because if it is continous then you can never terminate because there are infinite points in the line ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your calculating the mid point only in the first half of the line and then bisecting it each time because you are only calculating between start and mid. `GraphLocation point = GetMidPoint(start, midPoint);`
How about calling GetMidPoint() recursively? A stop condition would be to limit the depth of the recursion, so you dont get to many points.

Comment: yes you are right and there lies my problem. I am not able to figure out the stopping condition for the recursion.

Comment: Why not giving an integer of eg. 2000 to the first call of GetMidPoint(). Everytime the recursion goes deeper you subtract 1 until you have reached 0 ?